# print letters and number on same field with bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create bash script with below expected output ..which the last digit contains numbers and letters

```
id is 1a
id is 1b
id is ..
id is 1z
id is 11
id is 12
id is 13
id is ..
id is 2a
```

i try with below script but that doesn't work

```
#!/bin/bash
for ID in {1..9}{a..z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}
do
echo "id is $ID"
done
```

Comment: why 11/12/13 when you say "which the last digit contains numbers and letters "?

Comment: @SMA The last digit (obviously he/she means the last character) of 11/12/13 are digits. What's the problem?

Comment: last digit contains **number and letters** but 11 is just number and not letter

Comment: @SMA I think the expected behavior is more than clear from the provided code `{1..9}{a..z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}`.

Comment: @SMA mean for digit last character .. Non Native English Speaker (like me) face problem to explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a nested for loop.

```
for i in {1..9}; do
    for j in {a..z} {1..9}; do
        ID=$i$j
        echo "id is $ID"
    done
done
```

Comment: @lurker I'm just trying to match what the OP wants. I suppose he/she's gonna do something with `$ID`.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and agreed they might use the `$ID` later. I did upvote your answer as a clear way to accomplish their task.

Comment: @lurker ID is an example but my request is related http links http://www.example.com/se/?hash="$ID"4z2 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Bash does not appear to permit mixing sequences with other values/sequences (eg. `{1..9,a}`. You should provide one argument for each new sequence.

You can do the following:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 for ID in {1..9}{a..z} {1..9}{1..9}
 do
    echo "id is $ID"
 done
```

Comment: Thanks for the precision. Hope this helps op to understand how to deal with bash when mixing multiple sequences.